# rabbitmq performance check

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I was trying to perform LoadTest on the RabbitMQ messaging to see to what extent it can take messages into the queue and transfer it to the target machine over shovel.

### Steps i followed:

1. producer has 20 threads. Each thread sends message to a dedicated queue(Say suppose ProducerQueue1 -- ProducerQueue20).The message is of size 51Mb each. The messages are sent in random interval using java.util.Random(50) seconds.
2. After each message sent at random seconds(A random second between 1- 50), 
   there is a sleep of 2 minutes.Therefore each of the producer threads sleep for 
   2 min after every send.
3. The messages are sent in a infinite while loop.
4. There are shovels from each dedicated queue to the consumer side dedicated queues(Say suppose ConsumerQueue1 --- ConsumerQueue20).
5. The link speed is 100mbps.

### Issue observed:

1. Initially the messages are transferred with no issues, but after some time the NETWORK AT CONSUMER SIDE IS CHOKED.
   The reason for choking is that after certain period of time, even if 4/5 out of 20 thread's random second coincides, then the consumer receives close to 250Mb message in one shot. Since the network speed is 100mbps as mentioned above, the network gets choked.
2. Due to this, the shovels will not be able to exchange heartbeats to stay in "running" state. The leads shovels to move from "running" to "terminated" state. The shovels try to establish a connection depending upon the "reconnect delay".
3. Due to break in shovels at producer side, the queues at the producer starts getting accumulated.

### My Question:

The consumer's rabbitMq memory starts increasing as the queues start accumulating more messages. The memory is crossing the water mark. The purpose of water mark is not served. I have 16gb ram and i have  set watermark to 40%(i.e 6.4gb ram). But still the memory shoots up to 10gb and doesnt recover and the producer system hangs.

Can any one please answer my question. and also tell me can there be any other reason for network choking which i mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:spring-rabbitmq]? You should ask pure rabbitmq questions on the rabbitmq-users google group - that's where the rabbitmq engineers hang out.

Comment: I am using spring based rabbitmq. Thats the reason i added spring-rabbitmq also. Yes, i understand that its a pure rabbitmq issue.. Sorry for the wrong tagging. I wil respost in google group.. Thanks for the help.